# Functions on reduced schemes are determined by their values at each point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

This is an exercise in Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, namely 5.2.A.

> Let $X$ be a reduced scheme. If $a\in \mathscr{O}_X(X)$ is such that its image in $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ lies in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{p}$ for each $p\in X$, then $a = 0$.

I am able to show that a scheme is reduced iff $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is reduced for each $p\in X$, but I am not sure how to use this to prove the above statement.

Comment: Can you do this for the affine case?

Comment: @KReiser Haha I see now. In the affine case the image of $a$ lies in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_p$ means exactly $a\in p$, and the intersection of all primes is the nilradical. Therefore $a = 0$. Now a scheme is covered by affine opens, by the unique gluing property of sheaves, $a = 0\in\mathscr{O}_X(X)$ since its image in every affine open is $0$.

Comment: Good job! Remember as you get further in to algebraic geometry that computing on affines is a great place to start.

Comment: If you think of $a$ as a function, you should interpret $a \in\mathfrak m_p$ as of "$a$ vanishes at $p$". Then the statement is what everybody would believe: A function vanishing anywhere is the zero function.

That intuitive picture does not work anymore, when u have nilpotent elements. Nilpotent elements is one aspect which clearly separates the classical algebraic geometry with varieties (where $f$ vanishes if and only if $f^n$ vanishes) from the modern (or not so modern anymore?) language of schemes due to Grothendieck.